# CQRS: Command validity and UI

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, cqrs

I am currently researching if CQRS can be applied when building a particular system and have some questions I cannot easily find answers for.

In CQRS commands are used to respond to user actions. Users select the actions they want via UI and UI layer knows which commands will handle them.

However sometimes commands are not valid based on the context, such as user role, entity business state (public, archived) and user's relationship with the entity (for example, a ticket has reporter and person assigned).

Commands can check this as a part of overall validation. Obviously if the command is not valid for particular entity state it should not make any changes, therefore the validation and changes should be wrapped in a transaction if applicable.

This is all good and necessary, but we need to know if the command is valid within UI layer (for the context, we don't care about full validation here) so the appropriate UI element like button or menu item will simply be omitted if its not applicable. Therefore it seems to me that the read model for details/update views should return list of valid commands. Also if there is a read model that lists entities similar security trimming is needed here too, using the same rules and code.

As a bonus, some entities have state that is dependent on time, therefore it cannot be stored in the model but must be determined at runtime by using current server time.

The fact that read model cannot store such information is also apparent because it cannot be known without a context.

As I see to handle this in a user friendly and clean manner without violating DRY (so as not to duplicate business logic) we have to bend CQRS here a bit by appending additional query conditions based on context and business state checking and add list of valid commands within read models, therefore these system aspects become less separated and *the process of returning read models involves command handler*.

Perhaps I am worrying here too much and security trimming can be allowed to violate CQRS principles by being cross-cutting concern?

Answer (score 1):

Your basic assumption is correct. A command should only be sent to the application if it has a very high chance to succeed. Only valid commands should be available to any given UI and a basic client-side validation should occor as well.

Concerning your sencond question: If the state of your domain model changes when time passes, then these changes are domain events, whiih in turn can be explicitly modeled and handled by projections to update the read model(s) accordingly.